# Авторизация на php

Tags: php, mysql, авторизация

Здравствуйте нужна помощь. 
Есть у меня файлик с формой авторизации и выглядит он вот так.

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="login.php">
<a href="#" id="flipToRecover" class="flipLink">Забыли?</a>
<input type="text" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" value="Email" />
<input type="password" name="loginPass" id="loginPass" value="pass" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Вопрос так ли я прикрепил php файл login.php?

И второй вопрос. 
Есть файлик login.php

```
// Страница авторизации

# Функция для генерации случайной строки
function generateCode($length=6) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHI JKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $code = "";
    $clen = strlen($chars) - 1;  
    while (strlen($code) < $length) {
            $code .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];  
    }
    return $code;
}

# Соединямся с БД
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("testsite");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    # Вытаскиваем из БД запись, у которой логин равняеться введенному
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_password FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    # Сравниваем пароли
    if($data['user_password'] === md5(md5($_POST['password'])))
    {
        # Генерируем случайное число и шифруем его
        $hash = md5(generateCode(10));

        # Записываем в БД новый хеш авторизации и IP
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_hash='".$hash."' ".$insip." WHERE user_id='".$data['user_id']."'");

        # Ставим куки
        setcookie("id", $data['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30);

        # Переадресовываем браузер на страницу проверки нашего скрипта
        header("Location: check.php"); exit();
    }
    else
    {
        print "Вы ввели неправильный логин/пароль";
    }
}
```

Правильно ли все написано? Пока только учусь.

Comment: @Сяськаа, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Извините

Comment: @Сяськаа не совсем понял в чем вопрос? или вы просто хвастаетесь кодом? :)

Comment: ахаха) Нет)) Просто я относительно недавно изучаю такую великолепную вещь как программирование. 
И вот возник вопрос. Есть php код,как его подключить к той форме? Где-то я читал,что нужно просто добавить строчку 
<form id="login" method="post" action="login.php">

А код php выложил,чтобы сказали,верно ли он написан,если нет - то что нужно исправить.
С уважением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел несколько недоработок и одну ошибку.
**HTML**

- Если у Вас не подключен javascript к
     форме, использование id="login" и других id не
     обязательно, скорее лишнее;
- Имя полей в html должно соответствовать с ключем массива $_POST['key'] в PHP.

**PHP**

- Переменные `$_POST['login'] и $_POST['password']`, будут пустые, т.е равны значению False, так как у Вас другие имена в html форме;
- Функцию generateCode - можно заменить на `$hash = md5(microtime()); или rand()...`
- Использование двойного мд5, возможно ошибка ` if($data['user_password'] === md5(md5($_POST['password'])))ёж
- Лучше посчитать сразу, чем давать лишнию нагрузку скрипта. Нагрузка будет не заметна, но все-же (Это так придираюсь) `setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30);`
- Использование exit в фрагменте `header("Location: check.php"); exit();` - бессмысленно;
- Лучше использовать для вывода текста оператор echo чем print. По оптимизации echo быстрее;
- Использовать условия такие как у Вас бывают не очень удобные. Лучше использовать так:

  ```
  if(empty($_POST['submit']))    
     exit("Вы ввели неправильный логин/пароль");
  // дальше код $query = mysql_query...
  ```

Comment: Благодарю!)

Comment: Обращайтесь =)